# Java : dynamic matrix for cinema project

Tags: java, matrix

im working on a cinema project and i want to implement a hall creation, thing is i want it to be dynamic, so i put the values i want in a JPanel and it pops me out a theatre with the rows and columns i entered, with some kind of icon that changes color when i click it, that way i can create a theatre with the seats and aisles the way i want. I have read that it can be done with a bidimensional array (or matrix), thing is, when i want to get the values from the JPanel in the matrix, it says i cant get the value from a non-static to a static reference. Is it possible to do? Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are inherently static, once they are set, their length cannot be changed.  So with a two dimensional array, the width and height are fixed.  Try using a two dimensional ArrayList instead of an array.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Seats>> theater = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Seats>>();
```

Now, this functions that same way as the array's you're using, except now the ArrayLists are non static.

To navigate

```
theater.get(index); \\Returns the ArrayList(the row) at index

theater.get(index).get(seatNumber); \\Returns the seat at row index and seat number;
```